# converting Bathymetry real world co-ordinates to normalised co-ordinates in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I downloaded BathyMetry Data from online resources the resource contains X,Y,Z information represented below

```
 542484.986   5234278.220 -9.129072
 542487.256   5234278.236 -9.240440
 542489.601   5234278.253 -9.281879
 542491.871   5234278.269 -9.457996
 542494.216   5234278.286 -10.245342
 542496.486   5234278.303 -10.499158
 542498.831   5234278.320 -10.698585
 542501.101   5234278.336 -10.719304
 542484.962   5234281.554 -9.222311
 542487.232   5234281.570 -9.315549
 542489.577   5234281.587 -9.403607
```

Since openGL Es visible values range between `-1 and +1` ,,How to convert all the above mentioned `real world co-ordinates` into `normalised screen coordinates`

Answer (score 1):

You may have to normalise the values 'manually':

> normalised value = value / (maximum value in data set)

I'm not sure this can be done by OpenGL for you, but don't quote me on this.